# Deploying to the CloudHub fails with the error in the YAML

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mulesoft, mule4, cicd

I am trying to deploy the mulesoft application in to the DEV CloudHub using the Azure Devops CI/CD Pipeline. But when the application getting deployed in to the Cloud Hub it throws error like

`ConfigurationPropertiesException: YAML configuration properties only supports string values, make sure to wrap the value with \" so you force the value to be an string. Offending property is sharepoint.auth with value null"}`

Below is my DEV yaml file

```
# Sharepoint
sharepoint:
  maxCouncurrency : "2"
  siteUrl: "https://example.com/sites/D365Admin"
  auth:
##username: ""
##password: ""
  listener:
    path: "/sites/D365Admin/NP/SF"
    polling:
      frequency: "60" # In seconds
      startDelay: "30" # In seconds
  archive:
    path: "/sites/D365Admin/NP/SF-Archive"
```

I commented out the username and password as it is supplied in the Pipeline Variable. But I am not sure why am I getting the error on the `sharepoint.auth` Any suggestion what I am missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message seems pretty clear. The property `sharepoint.auth` doesn't has any value, it has a value of `null`, which is not allowed. Only strings are allowed and `null` is not a string. Try commenting it or assigning it an empty string (`""`). If you are not using it for anything just comment it.

Comment: Thank you so much.. After successfully deploying I am running to a different issue I posted another question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71948413/mule-application-listener-is-not-working-as-expected Can you please help me with it.. Appreciate all your help